# Need help for regex design in system.webServer rewrite rule in web.config

Tags: asp.net, regex, web-config

I am redirecting a lot of old pages because of a new webdesign. However I have run into one little issue.

I want to redirect:
www.domainname.com/Default.aspx

But not redirect

www.domainname.com/somesub/Default.aspx

I need it written like this:

```
<rule name="301 Redirect Default">
  <match url="???????" />
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domainname.com/index.php" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Where the questionmarks mark the regex I need.

Can anyone help?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
<match url="^Default\.aspx" />
```

Also see e.g. [this article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) regarding IIS rewrite rules.